# TextBox isEnabled binding dependant on combobox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winapp

So i have a ComboBox bound to a list of items. { A,B,C,D,E }

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbDMS" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" SelectedValue="{Binding Type,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="cmbDMS_SelectionChanged" />
```

also a TextBox.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding isTypeB}" Grid.Row="6" Width="250" Margin="0,2" />
```

I cannot figure out how to update the TextBox isEnabled property once the ComboBox SelectedValue has changed to B. It works once i exit and come back into the view but i want it to be instant.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "isTypeB"? Have you mistaken this for [a different site](http://www.psychicfriendsnetwork.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had some problems in the past with binding to `SelectedValue` and it properly raising events. Unless you have an explicit reason, I like to bind to the `SelectedItem`

The issue i have found with this operation, is that the binding to the `bool` object will not necessarily get updated via the changing of the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`

If you would like the two to be linked, an easy way to do this is to raise the Property changed event for the `bool isTypeB` property within the setter of the `"Type"` propery:

(as i dont know the Type of "Type" i will assume it is a string):

```
public string Type
{
  get{...}
  set
  {
    //...set logic
    RaisePropertyChanged(); //will notify when "Type" changes
    RaisePropertyChanged("isTypeB"); //will notify that isTypeB is changed
  }
}
...
public bool isTypeB => Type == "TypeB";
```

Reference for `RaisePropertyChanged`:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done a sample for you to understand it. 
Since it's more of a view based thing, I suggest using a converter and include the code in the view and converter itself. See the code below. I tested it and it is working fine at my end.

**When you select B the textbox is enabled, when selection changes to any other, the textbox is disabled.**

**XAML Code :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:TestConverter x:Key="TestConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="329,0,0,0">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDMS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="top" Width="120" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="B"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="D"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="E"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Height="60" Width="250" Margin="0,2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cmbDMS, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**TestConverter.cs Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModel
{
    public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var si = value.ToString();
                if (si.Equals("B"))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Binding works for the first time and later it doesn't, your notification about changing the property may not work. So make sure you binds to a property which is DependencyProperty or in your setter you raise PropertyChanged event (a member of INotifyPropertyChanged interface).